# Is Always Encryption feature is just ONLY for SQL Server ? How do I encrypt data during data transit to client?

Tags: sql-server, encryption, always-encrypted

I have enabled Always Encrypted in SQL Server Management Studio. I am able to see encrypted data when I query for data in SSMS.

Application which I have written in c#, which still shows plain text data when I fetch these data using code. So do I have to have different encryption mechanism in code side?

Sharing best practices shall help

Comment: Always Encrypted *isn't* an SSMS feature, it's a SQL Server feature. Have a read of the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/security/encryption/always-encrypted-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15).

Comment: Agreed, I am trying to understand how do I make sure my data obeys GDPR. Because my c# code logs the data still in plain text. so do I need to have different level of encryption on code side?

Comment: Encryption isn't a magic wand. What *threat model* are you trying to protect against? That informs your decision on a) whether Always Encrypted is an appropriate tool and b) whether additional security is required. The data is encrypted in transit (title of your question), it's en-/de-crypted by the client side connection library

Comment: I am not going through threat model approach , As per GDPR statement "Personally Identifiable Information" shall be encrypted. So I am trying to understand best practices. I am using Microsoft Azure SQL.

Comment: @kudlatiger Encryption of PII data, under GDPR, isn't mandatory, at least for storage. It's when it's in transit it must be. For example, if you were sending data from yourself to another company which contains details of your clients and their addresses, they should be sent via an encrypted protocol (such as SSL), or the file itself should be encrypted. Encryption at source isn't required, however, can be a solution for adhering to GDPR. Another solution is minimisation of access.

Comment: Great, could u share the Gemba (facts) for your GDPR statement, so that I can use it to claim my design decisions? In addition, any link which has best practices in the Medical industry.

Comment: @kudlatiger no, each company has their own implementations of GDPR, and the company I work for is very likely going to have very different rules. For examples as I work in Insurance and deal with motor insurance as well, I have details of Convictions, which is likely you aren't going to be handling. The company you work for needs to agree on the implementation *they* want to adhere to GDPR and then implement that. If the company chooses to use encryption at source, then that *is* a solution, but it is one of several. Encryption is source is *not* mandatory under GDPR like you state.

Comment: Okay, now keeping GDPR aside, my other question is: Do I have to encrypt PII data when I send it in a log to cloud space? or will the cloud provider (Microsoft) shall take care of it?

Comment: When PII data is in transit, it needs to be encrypted, @kudlatiger . So if you were transferring it via HTTP, and the file itself wasn't encrypted, that would be against GDPR. This, however, is going more into law questions, and if this is the direction the conversation is going to go, you'd be better off on [law.se].

Comment: Data which comes through as Always Encrypted is decrypted client-side, it stays encrypted in transit. And if you are using SSL/TLS it's anyway encrypted